# Select the first span preceeding an img element (arbitrary dom elements in between)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't find a selector suited for my needs, that is get the first (and only) `.info` `span` element before `img` element. Please be patient, i'm new to jQuery:

```
<div> <!-- common parent -->
   <span class="info"></span>
   <p>Stuff</p><span>Other sfuff</span>
   <!-- p, span or possibly other dom element before img -->
   <img src="" alt="" class="highlight" />

   <span class="info"></span>
   <!-- here nothing precede img element -->
   <img src="" alt="" class="highlight" />
</div>
```

I've tried:

`$("img.highlight").prev("span.info")` (that is *immediately preceding sibling*) will fail in the first example while works in the second one.

`$("img.highlight").prevAll("span.info")` will fail with the second one because the first span will be selected too.

**EDIT**: to be more clean this is real code:

```
$("img.highlight").each(function() {
    $info = $(this).selector("span.info") // selector() to be replaced
    $info.text($(this).attr("src")); // Fill the right span.info
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you just want the first `span.info` in the common-parent `div`?

Comment: @lwburk nope, sorry English is not my mother language. I want the first preceeding span.info of each img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('img.highlight').prevUntil('img.highlight', 'span.info')`

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        $(this).prevAll('span.info');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FXaBQ/).

In the demo, I've added content to the info `span` elements and adjusted their CSS to make it clear what they've affected. But the same technique should work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for helping, maybe the question is not 100% clean, see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$("img.highlight").prevAll("span.info:first")
```